# Alias for azure activity log

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am attempting to create an azure policy which looks out for a certain type of **event (Create or Update Security Rule) in the azure portal's activity log**.

A look at the json for this event has confirmed that it is of type *'Administrative'* and has action *'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/write'* as shown by:

```
    "authorization": {
        "action": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/delete",
        "scope": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/xxx/securityRules/xxxx"
    },
```

I'm hoping to use these details to distinguish this event from the rest. However I first need an alias that allows me to access these and cannot find the appropriate one from the ones shown by:

```
Get-AzPolicyAlias -NamespaceMatch 'microsoft.insights' | select -ExpandProperty Aliases | select -Property Name -ExpandProperty Paths
```

which gives:

```
Name                                                                     Path                                          ApiVersions
----                                                                     ----                                          -----------
Microsoft.Insights/logProfiles/storageAccountId                          properties.storageAccountId                   {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/logProfiles/serviceBusRuleId                          properties.serviceBusRuleId                   {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/logProfiles/locations                                 properties.locations                          {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/logProfiles/locations[*]                              properties.locations[*]                       {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/logProfiles/categories                                properties.categories                         {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/logProfiles/categories[*]                             properties.categories[*]                      {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/logProfiles/retentionPolicy                           properties.retentionPolicy                    {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/logProfiles/retentionPolicy.enabled                   properties.retentionPolicy.enabled            {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/logProfiles/retentionPolicy.days                      properties.retentionPolicy.days               {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/isEnabled                                  properties.isEnabled                          {2016-03-01, 2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/condition.dataSource.resourceUri           properties.condition.dataSource.resourceUri   {2016-03-01, 2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/condition.dataSource.metricName            properties.condition.dataSource.metricName    {2016-03-01, 2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/condition.operator                         properties.condition.operator                 {2016-03-01, 2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/condition.threshold                        properties.condition.threshold                {2016-03-01, 2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/condition.windowSize                       properties.condition.windowSize               {2016-03-01, 2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/condition.timeAggregation                  properties.condition.timeAggregation          {2016-03-01, 2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/condition.dataSource.odata.type            properties.condition.dataSource.odata.type    {2016-03-01, 2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/actions[*].odata.type                      properties.action.odata.type                  {2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/actions[*].odata.type                      properties.actions[*].odata.type              {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/actions[*].sendToServiceOwners             properties.action.sendToServiceOwners         {2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/actions[*].sendToServiceOwners             properties.actions[*].sendToServiceOwners     {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/actions[*].customEmails                    properties.action.customEmails                {2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/actions[*].customEmails                    properties.actions[*].customEmails            {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/actions[*].customEmails[*]                 properties.action.customEmails[*]             {2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/actions[*].customEmails[*]                 properties.actions[*].customEmails[*]         {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/actions[*].serviceUri                      properties.action.serviceUri                  {2015-04-01, 2014-04-01}
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/actions[*].serviceUri                      properties.actions[*].serviceUri              {2016-03-01}
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs.enabled                       properties.logs[*].enabled                    {2017-05-01-preview, 2016-09-01, 2015…
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/metrics.enabled                    properties.metrics[*].enabled                 {2017-05-01-preview, 2016-09-01, 2015…
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/storageAccountId                   properties.storageAccountId                   {2017-05-01-preview, 2016-09-01, 2015…
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/workspaceId                        properties.workspaceId                        {2017-05-01-preview, 2016-09-01, 2015…
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/eventHubAuthorizationRuleId        properties.eventHubAuthorizationRuleId        {2017-05-01-preview, 2016-09-01, 2015…
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/eventHubName                       properties.eventHubName                       {2017-05-01-preview, 2016-09-01, 2015…
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/metrics[*].retentionPolicy.enabled properties.metrics[*].retentionPolicy.enabled {2017-05-01-preview, 2016-09-01, 2015…
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/metrics[*].retentionPolicy.days    properties.metrics[*].retentionPolicy.days    {2017-05-01-preview, 2016-09-01, 2015…
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/metrics[*].category                properties.metrics[*].category                {2017-05-01-preview, 2016-09-01, 2015…
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs[*].retentionPolicy.enabled    properties.logs[*].retentionPolicy.enabled    {2017-05-01-preview, 2016-09-01, 2015…
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs[*].retentionPolicy.days       properties.logs[*].retentionPolicy.days       {2017-05-01-preview, 2016-09-01, 2015…
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs[*].category                   properties.logs[*].category                   {2017-05-01-preview, 2016-09-01, 2015…
Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/scopes                              properties.scopes                             {2018-09-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-03-01-p…
Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/scopes[*]                           properties.scopes[*]                          {2018-09-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-03-01-p…
Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/condition                           properties.condition                          {2018-09-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-03-01-p…
Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/condition.allOf                     properties.condition.allOf                    {2018-09-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-03-01-p…
Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/condition.allOf[*]                  properties.condition.allOf[*]                 {2018-09-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-03-01-p…
Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/condition.allOf[*].field            properties.condition.allOf[*].field           {2018-09-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-03-01-p…
Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/condition.allOf[*].equals           properties.condition.allOf[*].equals          {2018-09-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-03-01-p…
Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/condition.allOf[*].containsAny      properties.condition.allOf[*].containsAny     {2018-09-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-03-01-p…
Microsoft.Insights/ActivityLogAlerts/enabled                             properties.enabled                            {2018-09-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-03-01-p…
```

Kindly help me figure out the correct alias

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible to write a policy against activity log events themselves.  However you can use Azure Policy to force Activity Logs to be routed to an event hub and then write a Function app to monitor and react to these.